# ElasticSearch no data node with curl

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

How do I create a no data node using curl? Documentation [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/node.html) says set `node.data` to `false`. Is this the right way?

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo' -d '{"node.data" : "false"}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create a no data node using curl. When you can access the node using curl, the node is already running and it's not possible to convert a running data node to a no-data node.

You can make node a no-data node by adding `node.data: false` to the `config/elasticsearch.yml` file and restarting the node.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477303/multiple-nodes-in-elasticsearch